# QgsLayoutItemScaleBar.setUnits does not work

Tags: pyqgis-3, units, scale-bar

I'm writing a plugin that allows to automatically export a map with a predefined layout, based on the content of the canvas.

I need to have a scale bar in nautical miles, so in my code I add a QgsLayoutItemScaleBar (code below).

```
scaleBar = QgsLayoutItemScaleBar(c)
scaleBar.setLinkedMap(global_map)
scaleBar.setStyle('Line Ticks Up')
scaleBar.setUnits(QgsUnitTypes.DistanceNauticalMiles) # this line to set the unit of scale bar in Nautical Miles  
scaleBar.setSegmentSizeMode(1) 
scaleBar.setNumberOfSegmentsLeft(0)
scaleBar.setNumberOfSegments(2)
scaleBar.setMinimumBarWidth(15)  
scaleBar.setMaximumBarWidth(40) 
sbf = scaleBar.font()
sbf.setPointSize(9)
scaleBar.setUnitLabel("MN")
scaleBar.setHeight(2) 
scaleBar.setPos(x + 2 * (w // 3) + 25, y + h - 20)
c.addItem(scaleBar)
QgsMessageLog.logMessage('SCALE BAR UNIT: {0}'.format(scaleBar.units())) # result is Nautical Miles
```

It seems that this line **scaleBar.setUnits(QgsUnitTypes.DistanceNauticalMiles)** doesn't work: when exporting my map, the scale bar is in map units. I tried to move this line of code, to use DistanceKilometers but still no change. When I ask **scaleBar.units()**, it's in Nautical miles so the information is understand but not apply.

Has anyone experienced this problem before? Could it be a bug?

Comment: @f.ashouri What is QGIS version you use? There is no problem in *3.24.3-Tisler* and *3.26.2-Buenos Aires*.

Comment: Well, it works in QGIS console but not as a standalone program. v3.*

Comment: @f.ashouri can you share your own script? It works as expected in my standalone script.

Comment: Oh, good. It is part of a larger code. The code above didn't work for me. Can you please post a complete script for me?

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find what the problem is. When I use the following script, it works as expected.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject, QgsLayoutItemScaleBar, QgsUnitTypes, QgsLayoutExporter

qgis_path = "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr"
project_path = "C:/Test/Test_Project.qgz"
layout_name = "LAYOUT_NAME"
map_name = "MAP_NAME_IN_LAYOUT"
export_pdf_path = "C:/Test/layout.pdf"

app = QApplication([])
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

qgs.setPrefixPath(qgis_path, True)
qgs.initQgis()

project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read(project_path)

# layout settings
layout_manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = layout_manager.layoutByName(layout_name)

m = layout.itemById(map_name)
scaleBar = QgsLayoutItemScaleBar(layout)
scaleBar.setLinkedMap(m)
scaleBar.setStyle('Line Ticks Up')
scaleBar.setUnits(QgsUnitTypes.DistanceUnit.DistanceNauticalMiles)
scaleBar.setSegmentSizeMode(1)
scaleBar.setNumberOfSegmentsLeft(0)
scaleBar.setNumberOfSegments(2)
scaleBar.setMinimumBarWidth(10)
scaleBar.setMaximumBarWidth(50) 
scaleBar.setUnitLabel("NM")
sbf = scaleBar.font()
sbf.setPointSize(9)
scaleBar.setHeight(2)
scaleBar.setPos(100, 100)
layout.addItem(scaleBar)

exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToPdf(export_pdf_path, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())

# app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting your code. It seems that you are calling an existing QGIS project, but I am loading a raster or vector layer directly using QgsRasterLayer or QgsVectorLayer. When we are talking of a standalone script, it means that we don't want to refer to any files that is created manually

Answer (score 3):

`QgsLayoutItemScaleBar.setUnit()` seems to expect a **class reference** of `QgsUnitTypes.DistanceUnit`, while `QgsUnitTypes.DistanceNauticalMiles` is an `int` attribute.

Try:

```
scaleBar.setUnits(QgsUnitTypes.DistanceUnit.DistanceNauticalMiles)
```

Comment: In fact, looks like that's the main difference in @KadirSahbaz's code snippet, too. Take my answer as a pointer to the actual issue then.

Comment: Thank you, I tested. This wouldn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

This is my standalone script:

```
from qgis.PyQt import QtGui
from qgis.core import *
import os
from qgis.PyQt import QtGui


os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "offscreen"
# Supply path to qgis install location
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr", True) # or the path that works for you

qgs = QgsApplication([], True)

# Load providers
qgs.initQgis()


export_pdf_path = '/path/to/your/output/directory/output.pdf'

fn = '/path/to/your/raster/image.tif'
layer = QgsRasterLayer(fn, "my_raster.tif")


project = QgsProject.instance()
project.addMapLayer(layer)
print('project:', project)
# layout settings
layout_manager = project.layoutManager()
# layout = layout_manager.layoutByName(layout_name)
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName('layout2')
layout_manager.addLayout(layout)
print('layout:', layout)

map1 = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
map1.setRect(20, 20, 20, 20)


# set the map extent
ms = QgsMapSettings()
ms.setLayers([layer]) # set layers to be mapped
rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.0)
ms.setExtent(rect)
map1.setExtent(rect)
layout.addLayoutItem(map1)
map1.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(5, 20, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map1.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(180, 180, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

scaleBar = QgsLayoutItemScaleBar(layout)
scaleBar.setLinkedMap(map1)
scaleBar.setStyle('Line Ticks Up')
print('before',scaleBar.units())
scaleBar.setUnits(QgsUnitTypes.DistanceKilometers)
print('before',scaleBar.units())
scaleBar.setNumberOfSegmentsLeft(0)
scaleBar.setNumberOfSegments(3)
scaleBar.setUnitsPerSegment(50000)
scaleBar.setMinimumBarWidth(10)
scaleBar.setMaximumBarWidth(50)
scaleBar.setUnitLabel("km")
scaleBar.setHeight(2)
scaleBar.setPos(100, 100)
scaleBar.update()
layout.addItem(scaleBar)

exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToPdf(export_pdf_path, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

Notice that I'm using `QgsUnitTypes.DistanceKilometers` and expect the scale bar in Kilometers. My sample data is in UTM and, accordingly, in meters. The resulting pdf grabs the CRS of the image, no matter what I put in `setUnits`. The irony is that it changes the scalebar units. The lines before and after `setUnits` prove that. The problem is that it doe not apply it in the pdf file.

Comment: If your other answer solved your problem, please undelete it. That means it is the solution worked for you.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Thanks a lot for your attention. The one that I deleted was not a good solution. I added the working solution now.

Comment: Is this a solution? It is unclear whether this is an answer or if it's just confirming the problem.

Comment: @Matt The answer that I posted yesterday is the solution

Answer (score 0):

For everybody who is still interested, I found the solution. We have to set the project crs with `project.setCrs(layer.crs())`. Of course you can define crs yourself instead of `layer.crs()`.